# Equivalent to XUL toolbaritem in Mozilla Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, xul

I am considering to migrate my XUL-based Firefox add-on to the SDK. My add-on integrates as small panel in the `BrowserToolbarPalette`, displaying 2 icons and a label – currently realized as XUL `toolbaritem`. The module `ui/button/action` is not sufficient for this task, a `ui/toolbar` would be too much.

Am I missing something or is it really impossible to implement this with the new SDK?

Comment: We decided to limit the SDK's apis to only single buttons. The underlying api is [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm).

Comment: So is it possible to build the add-on with the SDK and create the panel low-level using the `CustomizableUI` module?

Comment: Maybe? Haven't done it personally but I know that more complex things ( like the menu button in Firebug 3 ) are possible.